# Issue calling a stored procedure with one input parameter on a linked server on my local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, linked-server

I am setting up a SQL Server database and have been given access to call a stored procedure in a remote server to help populate some tables.

I created a linked server as SSIS in Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server Management Studio 2008 seem to not like `EXEC` statements in their SSIS packages for remote servers.

So having successfully set up linked server I try to execute my stored procedure with the following

```
Select * from OPENQUERY(LinkedServerName, 'exec  storedProc paramValue')
```

But get the following error

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure storedProc, Line 49
>   Invalid object name '#tmp_bl'.

I have tried to `Select` my Linked server but no luck.

Does anyone know what the exec statement should be so I can put it into a local SSIS package?

Comment: Can you explain why your SSIS package doesn't just connect directly to the second server? Why does it connect to the first server and then use a linked server?

Comment: There is some problem in storeproc sp, check for '#tmp_bl' text in that sp. Share the sp.

Answer (score 0):

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure storedProc, 
Line 49 Invalid object name '#tmp_bl'.
```

Looks like the SP you are calling, in turn tries to access a temp table named `#tmp_bl`.

So, when you try to run your SSIS package from design (BIDS) it validates the package and couldn't found temp table; so errors.

Solution: Create the temp table first (using SSMS/Sqlcmd) and then try to run the package; like

```
create table #tmp_tbl ....
```

If you are trying to run the package from command prompt using `dtexec` utility then make the `delayvalidation` property of the package control (control which actually executing your temp table; either DataFlow task or SQLTask) to `True` (`DelayValidation = True`). Which, will not validate to see whether temp table exist or not while validating your entire package.

Comment: hey guys, i sorted the issue, it was a config issue with my MS SQL management Studio - I needed to go into LinkedServer -> providers-> OraOLEDB.oracle 
Double click on this and it shows you the options – check the ‘Allow inprocess’ option.

Comment: @user1417337: you could write an answer to your own question, that way you might help someone else with a similar problem!

Comment: But why not connect directly to the server from SSIS? Why use a linked server at all? You're overcomplicating your process.